# Is it possible to segregate logger with name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

currently if I run `logger.debug('message')` I get output like this

`{"message":"message","level":"debug"}`

Is it possible to do something on creation of logger, so that the message will look more like this?

`{"message":"message","level":"debug","name":"someModule"}`

I would like in the end, for each module to customise its own logger, so it is clear form which module the logging came

In case winston logger has no function of this own, can you recommend one logging library that has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [custom-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-logger)

There you can define something like:

```
var log = require('custom-logger').config({ format: "%message% %level%[%timestamp%]: %name%" });
```

also, something more complex like:

```
log.new({
    alert: { level: 3, color: 'red', event: 'alert', format: '!!!!!%event% : %message% !!!!!' name: '%name%' }
});
```

And very simple like:

```
log.info("I see %d %s!", 3, "bananas");
```

Getting the output: **Outputs "I see 3 bananas!"**

For your specific question, you might add this to your code:

```
log.new({
   debug: { message: "This is the message" , level :"debug", name: "Your module name"}
});
```

To use the standard provided by the library:

```
log.new({
       fatal: { message: "THIS IS THE END!" , level :"fatal", name: "Your module name"}
    });
```

In case you want to define your own colors to have a better overview:

```
log.info().config({ color: 'cyan' }); //This should be declared as global
log.info('Hello World!');
```

Also, you can assign

```
try {
  eval('alert("Hello world)');
}
catch(error) {
  console.error(error);
  log.new({
     error: { message: error, level :"error", name: "Your module name"}
  });
}
```

Comment: I like custom logger, now the real question is how to define %name?

Comment: @Tree I updated the answers, to fit to your specific question

Comment: Thanks. If I understood correctly, I need to create log.new for each level, and add module name inside on module creation?

Comment: Yes, also, you can use a global configuration, like: `log.info().config({ color: 'cyan' });` and use the same configuration each time with `log.info('Hello World!');` the word will always appear in color cyan.
It works to you, please check this answer as the right answer.